# Tensorflow in Docker image disabled?

Tags: docker, heroku

I created a docker container with a trained deep learning model that predicts something. Its based on tensorflow and keras. The docker container works perfectly locally, but deployed on heroku it crashed because the tensorflow python module is missing. pip3 list shows that it is not installed. Since it is a deplendancy installed to the docker image I wonder if heroku is removing it because they do not want tensorflow to be running in hobby tier. Is that the case?

Comment: Can you make sure you run the exact image in heroku? Run your image with specific image tag, not with latest tag. Make sure you use same tag in both place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue was that per default the container locally runs with the root user, while heroku creates another user. Tensorflow was installed with the user flag, so it was available only to the root user. Best practice for heroku is to run the container locally also with another user. Then i had the same issue and could fix it quickly